# I have problem while installing requirement.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement black==19.3b0 
`(from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: none)`

ERROR: No matching distribution found for black==19.3b0 `(from -r requirements.txt (line 5))`

Please help me to solve this error.

I got this while  `pip install -r requirements.txt` and I use Mac

Comment: If you're using a mac, why the `linux` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are trying to install `black` in python2.

But `black` is only supported by `python3`

Do like this:

`pip3 install black==19.3b0`

or

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`